# How to enable anonymous access via IaC/REST API in artifactory 7.55?

Tags: artifactory

There was a setting in the past version of artifactory that could be set via configuration.xml/yaml called `anonAccessEnabled`. In version 7.55 it's no longer contained in the xml-file provided via `api/system/configuration` nor you can set it.

Are there any alternative to make sure the option is set?

Answer (score 0):

The option is present in the YAML configuration. Refer to this [documentation](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/security-configurations-in-artifactory-yaml)

Please execute the below command after creating a configuration.yml having the below content in the file and it will update the configuration accordingly. Tested the command in 7.55.10.

Contents to be added:-

```
security:
  anonAccessEnabled: true
```

API command to be executed:-

```
curl -u<username>:<password> -X PATCH "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/system/configuration" -H "Content-Type: application/yaml" -T configuration.yml
```

More details on how to apply the changes are present [here](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/apply-artifactory-yaml-configuration-changes).